# Flutter: send Data from TabBarView (StatefullWidgets) back to main Scaffold

Tags: dart, flutter

I want to create an App with Tabs to get the users input. The Problem is, that the different Tabs get different inputs, but i have to collect the inputs for the Database. My idea her was, that the main scaffold collects the inputs from all Tabs and write it in a database! My problem is that I don't know to send data from the tab (statefullWidget in an other file) to the parent class (Scaffold) or run a function from there!

Please help me and sorry for my bad English!

Jonas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a `Function` that can be called whenever you want.

### Small example

> MamaBear class

```
...

class _MamaBear extends State<MamaBear> {

 void hungryBear(String babyBear) {
   print("$babyBear is hungry");
 }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       body: Container(
                   child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      BabyBear(
                           "Mark",
                           (babyBear) {
                                hungryBear(babyBear);
                            },
       )])));}
```

> BabyBear class

```
class BabyBear extends StatefulWidget {
  final String babyBearName;
  final Function onBearAction;

  BabyBear(this.babyBearName, this.onBearAction);

  @override
   _BabyBear createState() => _BabyBear();
  }

class _BabyBear extends State<BabyBear> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Mama I'm hungry"),
          onPressed: () {
            widget.onBearAction(widget.babyBearName);
          }),
    );
  }
```

}