# how to get Data from Tabs in main flutter

Tags: flutter, tabs, appbar

I have a class where there are 2 Tabs (used DefaultTabController) . AppBar have Action button/Text to save the Edited Text in each tab either It may tab0 or tab1. Both Tabs are separate stateful widget . I don't know, how to get How to get EditedText/String from a tab when save action is pressed in main Class ?

I looked into the similar Question but didn't get  idea from it  [Flutter: send Data from TabBarView (StatefullWidgets) back to main Scaffold](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51010925/flutter-send-data-from-tabbarview-statefullwidgets-back-to-main-scaffold)
your help would be appreciated .Thanks a lot.

```
      class EditPocketMoney extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
       _EditPocketMoneyState createState() => _EditPocketMoneyState();
       }

      class _EditPocketMoneyState extends State<EditPocketMoney> {
     @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return DefaultTabController(
  length: 2,
  child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      appBar: AppBar(

        elevation: 0.0,
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        leading: IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.clear,color: Color(0xffE44663),), onPressed: (){Navigator.pop(context);}),
        title: Text('Edit',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white,fontFamily: 'SF Pro Text',fontSize: 17.0, ),),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: [
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: (){

                },
                child: Container(
                  margin:EdgeInsets.only(right:15.0 ),
                    child: Text('SAVE',style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xffE44663),fontFamily: 'SF Pro Text',fontSize: 17.0, ),)),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
        bottom: PreferredSize(

          preferredSize: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.8, 45.0),
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0,right: 18.0,top: 5.0),
            child: TabBar(
              unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white,
              labelColor:Colors.black ,
              labelPadding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              tabs: [

                Center(child: Text('Per Day',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),)),
                Center(child: Text('Per Month',style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0,fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),)),
              ],
              indicator: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                color: Colors.white,

              ),),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(children: [

        PocketMoneyPerDay(),
        PocketMoneyEditPerMonth()
      ])
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: You can pass a voidCallback to the separate tabs and define this voidCallback in the main file

Answer (score 1):

You can use any State Management package like Provider.

Refer this link for Provider https://medium.com/flutterpub/provider-state-management-in-flutter-d453e73537c5

I have given example using Provider package.

ChangeNotifier code:

```
class Data extends ChangeNotifier {
 TextEditingController tab_0_controller = TextEditingController();
 TextEditingController tab_1_controller = TextEditingController();

}
```

Tab0 TextField code:

```
TextField(
controller: Provider.of<Data>(context).tab_0_controller;
)
```